# Design page with static HTML or static DOM Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, createelement

today I've a question. Is faster to load a web page designed from static html example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Web page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Hi community</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Or by static Javascript with DOM? Example with document.createElement("...")

Comment: Static contents can be created using static html. Dynamic contents can be with DOM

Answer (score 3):

Serving the HTML directly would be the faster approach, as your browser only have to render the elements, and not manipulate the dom :)

Answer (score 3):

Populating HTML statistically is much faster than populating through javascript.

1. The HTML document gets downloaded
2. The parsing of the HTML document starts
3. HTML Parsing reaches `<script src="jquery.js" ...`
4. jquery.js is downloaded and parsed
5. HTML parsing reaches `<script src="xyz.js" ...`
6. xyz.js is downloaded, parsed and run
7. HTML parsing reaches `<link href="abc.css" ...`
8. abc.css is downloaded and parsed
9. HTML parsing reaches `<style>...</style>`
10. Internal CSS rules are parsed and defined
11. HTML parsing reaches `<script>...</script>`
12. Internal Javascript is parsed and run
13. HTML Parsing reaches `<img src="abc.jpg" ...`
14. xyz.jpg is downloaded and displayed
15. Parsing of HTML document ends

So, if you have static html loading with javascript will be overhead for page rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster to send a static html, because the client doesn't have to execute js. Sending complete HTML is also better for search engines, even if google can now execute js.

You can still use js to add elements in your DOM once the page is loaded

Answer (score -1):

Like others said, it is always faster to output static HTML rather than generating it dynamically using Javascript/JQuery. However, sometimes the content cannot be served directly and generating the HTML dynamically is the only choice. I have worked on a few applications where this was the case. In general, generate static HTML whenever you can.